# Convert lower triangle half to Symmertic matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I have a matrix which has to be transformed to a symmetric matrix using 
python numpy.

Apparently, using the following code in am able to transform to symmetric matrix .. this work fine for small matrix but for a large 150 * 151

```
 I get the following error...operands could not be broadcast together 
with shapes (151,150) (150,151) 



import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\vish_\\firstest\\demo\\002.csv', 
delimiter=',')

print(my_data)

[[ 0. nan nan]
[ 1.  0. nan]
[ 2.  3.  0.]]

<!-- code for symmetric matrix in file!>
m = np.tril(my_data) + np.tril(my_data, -1).T
print(m)
[[0. 1. 2.]
[1. 0. 3.]
[2. 3. 0.]]

<!-- code for saving matrix in file!>
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
m.tofile('foo2.csv',sep=',',format='%10.5f')

np.savetxt("foo2.csv", m ,delimiter=",",fmt='%f')


I get the following error...operands could not be broadcast together 
with shapes (151,150) (150,151)
```

Comment: Your error doesn't have to do with small vs large, you have incompatible shapes to add together.  Can you provide a desired output if the matrices were 3x4?

Comment: Which line produced the error?  We can guess it was `np.tril(my_data) + np.tril(my_data, -1).T`, but we might be guessing wrong.  You don't want that to happen, do you?

Comment: All i want is  a numpy function or snippet that would help to transform lower half of triangluar matrix to a complete symmetric matrix (for larger matrix).. I tried doing that with the above code and it worked for small 3* 4 matrix but for large matrix : it gives an error on this line np.tril(my_data) + np.tril(my_data, -1).T

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a square matrix. 150 x 151 is not a square matrix! The reason it worked for smaller example because it was a square matrix (3 x 3). The example on which you are trying to work is not a square matrix. Please there is a transpose operator in the code (see below towards right).

```py
m = np.tril(my_data) + np.tril(my_data, -1).T
```

For 150 x 151 the transpose will be 151 x 150 shape. The dimensions will not line up for the addition to happen. Best wishes

Comment: so could you pls help me with the a numpy function or snippet  that would help to transform  lower half of triangluar matrix to  complete  symmetric matrix (for large matrix)..Thanks in advance

Comment: Symmetry is defined with respect to a point, line or plane. For square matrix, that reference is the diagonal line, For a non square matrix (e.g. a 3x4 matrix), you can draw empty 3x4 cells' matrix on a paper and convince yourself that the diagonal that divides into symmetrical upper and lower halves is missing. I think symmetric matrix is only defined for square matrix. See this link here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) where it clearly says that "Because equal matrices have equal dimensions, only square matrices can be symmetric.". But what is your end goal of that matrix?